# Getting a Unable to exec g++.real error in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, makefile

I recently installed eclipse on Ubuntu.  I added the CDT plugin.  When I try to run the hello world program for c++ I get a make:***[src] Error 2 error.  In the console I get the Unable to exec g++.real error.  I have been looking up on stack and google how to fix this all morning and have had no luck. From what I can figure out, there is a problem with the makefile, but the CDT plugin makes that file automatically. Anyone have and ideas of what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you installed the C++ compiler?

Comment: Yes, isn't that the CDT plugin?

Comment: try running in the console `whereis g++`.

Comment: No.  The CDT plugin (as I understand it: I use Emacs not Eclipse) just lets Eclipse edit C++ files.  It doesn't contain a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with :

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

Then hopefully g++ should be added to your PATH.